# Min cost matching with outliers

Tags: algorithm, optimization, outliers

Given a complete bipartite graph G = (V1, V2; E), |V1|=|V2|=n and a non-negative cost for each edge the min cost bipartite matching problem finds a partition of G to n pairs of vertices connected by an edge, such that the total sum of the edges costs is minimized.

This problem can be solved using the [min cost flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) algorithm, by adding a source and sink vertices connected to each group with a weight 0 and a capacity 1.

But what if instead we get as an input a number m < n and want to find a partition of m pairs such that the total cost is minimized?

At first I thought we can just add another vertex at the beginning which is connected to the original source with weight 0 and capacity m and call it the new source, that way the maximum flow would be m and it should choose only m pairs.

However when I ran this algorithm using boost's min cost flow function a lot of times there were 2 big problems:

1) The flow in an edge wasn't always an integer (i.e. instead of 0 or 1 the flow was 0.5 for example).

2) There were many possible (non-integer) solutions so even for the same input with different order the algorithm outputted different results.

The moment I set m to be n both of these problems were resolved.

So my question is: is there a way to solve this problems and if not is there another algorithm that can solve the min cost bipartite matching with outliers problem?

Comment: Can you clarify the distinction between finding a set of m < n pairs where the total cost is minimized and finding a minimum-cost bipartite matching? Also, wouldn't outputting no pairs at all be a valid solution to your problem?

Comment: @templatetypedef Outputting no pairs would give us 0 pairs not m pairs, I now edited the question to clarify that we get m as an input.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X97001200)? Or [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117719/assignment-problem-finding-the-k-agents-with-the-best-assignment)?

Comment: @גלעדברקן yes, like the first link, thanks. The second link is also the same problem but the solution someone said there is what I already tried and didn't work, but in the first link they seemed to solve it.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I've just noticed they also said in the paper the solution I already tried and didn't work, so I think the problem was in my code, not algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the algorithm I described in the question and said that didn't work actually did work and it happened because of floating point error caused inside boosts min cost flow function, when I multiplied all the costs by 10000 all the problems were resolved.